# Checking if a binary search tree is a subtree (without using recursion!)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

A question i had been investing a bit of time in doing recursively ended up being bool isSubTree(BST &Tree)
where it accepts a Tree object as parameter, where i have done it as it accepts 2 nodes in the parameter, which was wrong of me.

How can we possibly check it without recursion?

note: the function is a BST class function, which in the main to compare both trees we will do MyOriginalTree.isSubTree(BST &theOtherTree), this will either return true or false.

Comment: Please explain further your question so we can understand , take a moment to learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: Is `isSubTree` a class method? Such as `BST::isSubTree(BST& Tree)`?

Comment: My bad, i edited the original post with more details!

Comment: *How can we possibly check it without recursion?* -- Turn the recursive function into an iterative one.  There is nothing special about this just because it is a tree.

Comment: Please check this link:- 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-binary-tree-is-subtree-of-another-binary-tree/

Also, next time provide code so that we can debug where it went wrong?

Comment: That's what i am having trouble with right now, I am not sure how to iterate this function as i am not experienced with bst that much, and most functions i write are recursive in bst

Comment: Traversals can be written as an iterative routine using stacks or queues.  Determine the traversal you're using and implement that traversal using the proper data structure.

Comment: Wikipedia often has good pseudocode examples of common algorithms.